# We made/We have made memories

Tags: present-perfect

What is the difference between ‘we made memories’ and ‘we’ve made memories” ?

Comment: The difference is exactly what the present perfect and simple past represent: "we made" is a statement of past fact, and "we've made" (= we *have* made) is something past that has a present implication.